# How to convert a string into it's real binary representation (UTF-8 or whatever is currently used)?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, utf-8, binary

I want to experiment with UTF-8 and Unicode, for that I want to build a small Website which helps me to understand the encoding better.

First I want the ability to enter some Text and then get the actual binary encoding of the string. For that I'm searching for a equivalent to ".GetBytes" from C# or Java. I do not want the resolved CharCodes!

Here a C# function I would like to reproduce in JavaScript

```
string ToBinary(string input)
{
    //this is the part I am looking for in JavaScript
    var utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

    var bytesFormatedToBin = utf8Bytes.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
    return string.Join(' ', bytesFormatedToBin);
}
```

Here some sample results:

- "abc" => "01100001 01100010 01100011"
- "@©®" => "01000000 11000010 10101001 11000010 10101110"
- "" => "11110000 10011111 10011000 10000000 11110000 10011111
  10011000 10000100"

Is there a way to achieve this in JavaScript?

Thanks.
Marc

Edit: Fixed truncated sample result.

Comment: `"abc".split('').map(i => i.charCodeAt(0).toString(2).padStart(8, '0')).join(' ');` something like this, you just need to take care of leading zeros, if I'm not missing something. Emojis may need further work, though.

Comment: If you evaluate "®".charCodeAt(0); you will get 174. 174 is the Unicode number of this character but it is not the actual value in memory if UTF-8 Encoded.  In UTF-8 this Char takes up two bytes "11000010" and "10101110". This is what I want to get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String.prototype.charCodeAt(...)` only works properly when the the string only contains ASCII characters. You'll have to use the standard `TextEncoder` if you want to deal with other characters:

```js
const te = new TextEncoder('utf-8')
function toBinaryRepr(str) {
    return Array.from(te.encode(str))
        .map(i => i
            .toString(2)
            .padStart(8, '0'))
        .join(' ')
}
// '01100001 01100010 01100011'
toBinaryRepr('abc')
// '01000000 11000010 10101001 11000010 10101110'
toBinaryRepr('@©®')
// '11110000 10011111 10011000 10000000 11110000 10011111 10011000 10000100'
toBinaryRepr('')
```

Warning: `TextEncoder` is not a global constructor in older versions of Node.js - if you get some errors saying `TextEncoder` is not defined, try importing it by:

```js
const { TextEncoder } = require('util')
```

Comment: Thanks, TextEncoder is exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: The Warning is a good information. I was already happy with the keyword "TextEncoder" with this I found the API documentation and now a door to a new world opens before me ;-)